# Validate endpoint with .p12

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have an endpoint that I need to hit and validate.

I have a generated .p12 file and a chain of certificates (Root and Intermediate) that I can use to validate.

Here is the code I currently am using which gives me this error:

`System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

var p12 = new X509Certificate2(
  Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Assets/Certs/p12filename.p12"),
  "TheRealPassword");
            
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(p12);
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
{
    var root = new X509Certificate2(
        Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Assets/Certs/Root.cer"));
                
    X509Chain CertificateChain = chain;
    CertificateChain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
                
    return CertificateChain.Build( root ); 
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler);

var url = "https://urlHere"
            
var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
  {
    RequestUri = new Uri(url),
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
  };
            
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

I'm not super well versed in using certs so it is perhaps something quite elementary. Of note if inside the ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback I return `true` I have no issues.

Update:
To clarify, how can I validate the end point I am hitting using my .p12 and the corresponding root and intermediate certificates. My assumption based on returning true in the call back giving me what I want is that I need to do these checks here.

Comment: What is your question? BTW the logic inside a callback is behind of my understanding, it makes zero sense to me.

Comment: That exception means you're returning `false` from your callback.  But the code in your callback is currently "does this computer trust the cert in some file on disk"... it doesn't look at the certificate that was used on the request at all, so if your computer did trust `root.cer` then you'd go from accepting nothing to accepting any cert for any endpoint (thus being open to man in the middle attacks).

Comment: @crypt32 I have updated my original post

Comment: @bartonjs thank you for that explanation that makes more sense now, it was a bit of an amalgamation of posts I had found which I obviously didn't fully understand. I have updated my original post explaining what I hope to achieve.

Comment: You need to check if server certificate chains to a root stored in your app? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes I believe that is correct